# Minimising Database Queries when using Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, post-meta

I'm working on a page which lists staff members for a large company and trying to minimise the number of times I'm forced to query the database as it gets quite complex and slow.

- `'person'` is a custom post type (there are about 300 people)
- `'date_accredited'` is a date field added via Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Only accredited staff will have a `'date_accredited'`.

I need to list every `'person'` BUT, with ALL accredited staff listed first (so about 20 accredited staff come at the top).

At the moment, I am doing a call to WP_Query like:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'people', 
    'no_found_rows' => true, 
    'meta_key' => 'date_accredited'
);
$people = new WP_Query($args);
```

After that I'm doing:

```
while($people->have_posts()): $people->the_post();      
    $my_post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'date_accredited', true);
    if (!empty($my_post_meta)) {
        array_push($accredited, $post);
    } else {
        array_push($notAccredited, $post);
    }
endwhile;
```

Leaving us with two arrays of 'person' objects. My thinking here was that I would be able to do something like the following to get the list I want:

```
foreach($accredited as $person):
    personTile($person);
endforeach;

foreach($notAccredited as $person):
    personTile($person);
endforeach;
```

I'm trying to avoid re-querying the database.

The `personTile();` function was supposed to output various info and HTML (`the_post_thumbnail()` and various Advanced Custom Fields fields), but what I'm realising now is that none of this is included in the post objects I get from `WP_Query()`, so I'm forced to use things like:

- `get_the_post_thumbnail($person->ID)`
- `get_permalink($person->ID)`
- `get_field('date_accredited', $person->ID)`

All of these cost another DB Query (each!), and worse still since they are in a loop each one happens around 300 times.

Is there any way to get the permalink, thumbnail and ACF fields to be included in the original DB Query? Would I need to resort to a custom MySQL Query???

Any other suggestions welcome!

Comment: Can't really think of an alternative here, execpt making use of transients or putting your results in a cache. You can have a look at a custom SQL query, but you will need to test its effiency. Remember, 100 small effecient db queries can be much faster as one or two ineffecient ones. Download query monitor plugin and test your results and make comparisons. Don't run it on a live site though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> All of these cost another DB Query (each!), and worse still since they are in a loop each one happens around 300 times.

Don't panic! The posts from your query are stored in WordPress' [object cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) (which is simply memory, unless you have a custom cache system in place).

All functions that operate on posts route through this cache, so in your case there's no extra database hit, even when you're not in "the loop".

You will however want to pop this line in, right after your query:

```
// http://wpseek.com/function/update_post_thumbnail_cache/
update_post_thumbnail_cache( $people );
```

This will run two extra queries (posts & post meta), which adds all thumbnails (attachments) for posts in the `WP_Query` instance to the same cache.

Otherwise you *will* end up with a lot of queries (two for each post that has a thumbnail).

**N.B:** There are a few `WP_Query` arguments that will change the way posts are cached:

- `update_post_meta_cache` (almost always yes)
- `update_post_term_cache` (if you don't need terms you can save a query here)
- `fields` (if not `all`, nothing is cached and above is ignored)
- `cache_results` (if false, nothing is cached and everything above is ignored)

Comment: Good explanation, I tried adding `update_post_thumbnail_cache($people);` and it made no performance difference though?

To confirm I wasn't going crazy I removed the following from my personTile() function:

    `if(has_post_thumbnail($person->ID)) { echo get_the_post_thumbnail($person->ID, 'person-thumbnail'); }`

Removing that gave a small performance boost as expected... from what you're saying I was expecting to see about half the same performance boost from using update_post_thumb_cache?

Comment: Where I'm really confused is that my $person object from the query only gives me: ID, post_author, post_date, post_date_gmt, post_content, post_title, post_excerpt, post_status, comment_status, ping_status, post_password, post_name, to_ping, pinged, post_modified, post_modified_gmt, post_content_filtered, post_parent, guid, menu_order, post_type, post_mime_type, comment_count, filter

Comment: This is from examining print_r($people); and I use ACF's get_field() function quite a lot. Is there any way to just examine the object cache and see what's being stored?

Comment: Measuring performance "by eye" isn't really very effective. And yes, your `$person_object` should only have those properties. All meta is stored in another object (in the cache), linked by post ID. Can you try installing [Debug Queries](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-queries/) and see what actual queries are firing.

Comment: Quite a lot of queries, none very time consuming:

Total query time: 0.04489s for 49 queries.
Page generated in 2.31387s, 98.06% PHP, 1.94% MySQL

Comment: I guess this means I'm completely wrong and the bottleneck is in my PHP somewhere? although I'm more or less just spitting out values, the most intensive thing I can see is there are date comparisons...

Comment: Is there a *significant* difference in page generation time for a "regular" page/post (i.e. one not showing people)? This would help rule out if it is indeed your code that is the troublemaker, or a more global issue like your server stack/WordPress install.

Comment: Everything else runs smooth, I think it is the code, but I don't think there exists a much more efficient way to do it. It does just spit out info from the query, but quite a lot and it loops 300 times.

Commenting out different logical sections, they seem to shave similar amounts of time off (no 1 section that takes up a lot of time).

Have got it down to a 3second page load, and probably going to move to hosting with full page caching so it won't really be an issue.

Perhaps I was just (naively) surprised at how slow PHP was being, but this has helped me understand much better so thank you!